# significance of Django Default tables

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django comes with default tables like  `AuthGroup`, `AuthGroupPermissions` , `AuthPermission`, `AuthUser`, `AuthUserGroups`, `AuthUserUserPermissions`, `DjangoAdminLog`, `DjangoContentType`, `DjangoSession` and `DjangoSite`. What is the significance of each table?

I know that these tables comes from the apps included in the `settings.py` file, but I really dont understand the need to use some of the following tables above, such as `Permissions` and `Groups`. Where will I exactly use these tables?

Answer (score 5):

The significance of the tables:

`AuthGroup`: Contains your groups, just id and name

`AuthPermission`: Contains the permissions of your project id, codename and a ForeignKey to the `ContentType` (Model) they belong to

`AuthGroupPermissions`: Table to keep the many to many relation between `AuthGroup` and `AuthPermission` (which permissions each group has)

`AuthUser`: Your users - username is the primary key

`AuthUserGroups`: Table to keep the many to many relation between `AuthGroup` and 
`AuthUser` (which users belong to each group)

`AuthUserPermissions`: Table to keep the many to many relation between AuthUser and AuthPermission (which permissions each user has)

`DjangoAdminLog`: Records actions (insert/delete/update) your admin users do

`DjangoContentType`: Contains the content types of your project -- a content type is actually a Model in general - more info here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

`DjangoSession`: Contains session information (session key, data and when it expires), more info here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

`DjangoSite`: Contains the sites your application can be used on - more information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Now, you answer your other question, you don't actually need to use these tables yourself. You will use the django ORM to create Users, Groups, Permissions etc and these tables will be updated through the ORM.